# Does a series with bounded partial sums converge if the summands go to $0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$, $\ldots$ be a sequence of real numbers. Suppose that the sequence $(S_n)$ is bounded, where $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ and that $a_n \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$. Does this imply that $(S_n)$ converges?

Comment: Try finding a counterexample.  I assume that $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$.

Comment: Notice that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1/k = \infty$, so you might draw inspiration from that.

Comment: I think an=1/k then Sn is not bounded....!

Comment: If it sums to infinity, of course it is not bounded.  I intended you to "draw inspiration from that." If I gave a complete answer, there would be no way for you to be inspired!  But I see others have given you full answers.  My intention was for you to observe that, since the $1/k$ values go to zero, as do their negative counterparts, and since you can put enough of them of the same sign together to go as far as you like, you can link them together to make an oscillating sum that has no limit but remains bounded.

Answer (score 9):

This is not true. Consider the sequence $(a_n)$ given by
$$
a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots = 1, \underbrace{-\frac12, -\frac12}_2, \overbrace{\frac13, \frac13, \frac13}^3, \underbrace{-\frac14, -\frac14, -\frac14, -\frac14}_4, \overbrace{\frac15, \frac15, \frac15, \frac15, \frac15}^5, \ldots.
$$
Then clearly $a_n \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$ and $S_n$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$. However, there are both infinitely many $n$ for which $S_n=0$ and infinitely many $n$ for which $S_n = 1$, so $(S_n)$ is not convergent.

If all $a_n$ are positive then $S_n$ must be convergent, because then $(S_n)$ is a bounded and increasing sequence.

Answer (score 1):

(1,-1/2,-1/2,1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4,-1/8,-1/8,-1/8,-1/8,-1/8,-1/8,-1/8,-1/8,...).

This sequence converges to 0 and the series oscillates between 1 and 0 (Consider S_{1+2+...+2^n})